# What are chocolate bars for?

Tags: candy-box

I got a chocolate bar from the frog, and melted it all over my sword to make it better. I've since found more, what can I do with them?

Comment: Where do you find more?

Comment: How do you melt the bar on the sword?

Comment: @TheCowMan You should start a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have more than one chocolate bar. If you have more, it should display

> You have 2 chocolate bars \o/ (a bug ? Oo)

Because it isn't intended to have more than the one bar, you can't do anything with the additional bars.

Comment: If you finish the game, there is a way to get more chocolate bars.

Comment: @Zonko: Via the computer? Oww, my bad :D

Comment: exactly, and you get more chocolate bars with... bugs, you get it.